# ng test "Cannot resolve 'fs'" after updating to Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After upgrading my Angular project to 8, I get this error when running `ng-test --source-map false`.

**Note:** I could not find an import of `fs` *anywhere* in my project code. AFAIK, my project has no special need to access the filesystem.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\src\myproject\node_modules\resolve\lib'
resolve 'fs' in 'C:\src\myproject\node_modules\resolve\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\src\myproject\node_modules\resolve\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in C:/src/myproject/src/
        using description file: C:\src\myproject\package.json (relative path: ./src/)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\src\myproject\package.json (relative path: ./src/fs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\src\myproject\src\fs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\src\myproject\src\fs.ts doesn't exist
```

It looks like there is a library called `resolve` which requires `fs`. Here is what I found about `resolve`:

```
yarn why resolve
yarn why v1.16.0
[1/4] Why do we have the module "resolve"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
[4/4] Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "resolve@1.12.0"
info Has been hoisted to "resolve"
info Reasons this module exists
   - Hoisted from "tslint#resolve"
   - Hoisted from "grunt-cli#liftoff#resolve"
   - Hoisted from "@angular-devkit#build-angular#postcss-import#resolve"
   - Hoisted from "@angular-devkit#build-angular#@babel#core#resolve"
   - Hoisted from "grunt-cli#liftoff#rechoir#resolve"
   - Hoisted from "@angular#cli#pacote#normalize-package-data#resolve"
=> Found "grunt#resolve@1.1.7"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "grunt#grunt-cli" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "grunt#grunt-cli#resolve"
Done in 0.71s.
```

It seems normal that command-line tools like the angular CLI build and tslint should access the filesystem... so why is my project failing?

All of the above libs mentioned in `yarn why` (tslint, grunt-cli, angular-devkit, angular/cli) are listed under `devDependencies`, which seems OK to me.

**Update**

After working through a few other issues, I'm getting this error now on both `ng serve` and `ng test`. Here are my tsconfig files:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't add `node` types to your tsconfig.

It should be something
```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I generated a new, blank project from the CLI, which is working normally. I copied all of the contents from the three tsconfig files (.json, .app.json, .spec.json) from the new project to my old project. On `ng build` I still get the same error. On `ng test` I now get a different error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120512/jasmine-errors-after-upgrading-to-angular-8

Comment: Updated the OP with the current contents of my tsconfig files.

Comment: FYI [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) is used during compilation by build tools, not your app code.

Comment: @msanford Is there any more info I can provide to help figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long trial-and-error elimination process, I found the culprit:

```
import {hasOwnProperty} from 'tslint/lib/utils';
```

I accidentally imported a `tslint` utility function into my application source code. Oops!